# Where is stored the head title of Wordpress plugin in the Admin area?

Tags: wordpress

where should I search for the `title` in the `head` of a Wordpress plugin?

I want to change the title that is located in the head of the admin panel of Wordpress. The plugin has it's own page title that is the name of the plugin and I want to change it to another language.

If it is stored in a function, where should I look for it?

Comment: Do you want to change the name of the plugin or the name of that page of the plugin?

Comment: @KomalR I want to change the name of the page -> the title that is in the head of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cleared up that you want to change the name of the page, please try to locate the code that looks like this:

```
add_submenu_page( string $parent_slug, string $page_title, string $menu_title, string $capability, string $menu_slug, callable $function = '' );
```

You can change the $page_title variable of the page who's title you want to change. There could be multiple such functions.

I understand you might have to go through multiple files in your plugin folder but different developers work differently. Some put everything in one file, some more categorically. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to search for it. I will get back to you with my findings.

Comment: I found it, the exact function was used `add_submenu_page`. Thank you again! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope below helps:
[How rename a plugin title > Wordpress > Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049759/how-rename-a-plugin-title-wordpress-dashboard)

Please check once.

Thanks

Comment: I want to change the title that is in the head, not the plugin name.