# Wordpress: rename Toolbar link

Tags: wordpress, hook

I need to rename a Toolbar link, take a look at the capture to see what I mean.

I found this line of code to remove a link  `$wp_adminbar->remove_node('wp-logo');`

But nothing to 'rename'.

[image]

Comment: Which plugin you are using for that?

Comment: @KrupalPanchal this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicate-post/ You might want to see this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/rename-link-in-tool-bar-to-copy/

Comment: Have you tried statically with above-given reference link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this question [How rename a plugin title > Wordpress > Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049759/how-rename-a-plugin-title-wordpress-dashboard)

You may use the `gettext` WordPress filter to achieve rename your menu in your plugin or theme `functions.php` file:

```
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
switch ( $translated_text ) {
    case 'Copy to a new draft' :
        $translated_text = 'CLONE';
        break;
}
return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```