# How to rename submenu in toolbar in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have two plugins installed, which has generated two "Events" submenu in my toolbar. I would like to rename one of them to be able to make a difference.

I have found this topic:
[how to rename plugin title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049759/how-rename-a-plugin-title-wordpress-dashboard)
With this I can achieve to rename BOTH "Events" to any other title:

```
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
switch ( $translated_text ) {
    case 'Event' :
        $translated_text = __( '3rd party Events', 'Event' );
        break;
}
return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

The problem with this is that it renames both of my Event menu and I only want to rename the first.

With this code I can target the admin menu to get the complete tree in the source code and get the plugin's unique name, but this only gets me admin menu, not the toolbar.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'myRenamedPlugin' );

function myRenamedPlugin() {

    global $menu;
    $searchPlugin = "pgl_wp_files"; // Use the unique plugin name
    $replaceName = "New Name for Plugin";

    $menuItem = "";
    foreach($menu as $key => $item){
        if ( $item[2] === $searchPlugin ){
            $menuItem = $key;
        }
    }
    $menu[$menuItem][0] = $replaceName; // Position 0 stores the menu title
}
```

There is another topic discussing the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63129650/wordpress-rename-toolbar-link), but this also renames ALL with the same name.
How do I target the exact menu item (not just the ones with matching name) in the Toolbar to rename?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at the code and there isn't any filters that I can see. So you basically will need to do a hack.

**Option 1**

Get at the node you want to change (by id). Remove that node, then change the title and add it back

```php
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', function () {
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    // Get the node
    $node = $wp_admin_bar->get_node('some-event-id');

    // Remove the node
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('some-event-id');

    // Change the node title
    $node->title = 'Events #2';

    // Add the node back to the menu
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu($node);
}, 9999999, 0);
```

**Option 2**

Capture the output buffer of the admin menu, do some string or regex find and replace, then output the buffer

```php
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', function () {
    ob_start();
    
    add_action('wp_after_admin_bar_render', function () {
        $buffer = ob_get_clean();
        // do some find/replace 
        echo $buffer;
    }, 1, 0);
    
}, 9999999, 0);
```

There are pros/cons to each, and neither would be perfect. But as far as I can tell, that is your best shot.

Comment: Awesome, great!